# jQuery window.resize issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery to stick footer to the bottom. The code works, but when the browser is resized it needs to refresh for the footer to stick to the bottom. I dont want it to need to be refreshed. I tried using the jquery resize method but it doesnt work.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
          var vwptHeight = $(window).height();
          if (vwptHeight > bodyHeight) {
            $("#footer").css("position","absolute").css("bottom",0);
          }

            $(window).resize(function() {
                $("#footer").css("position","absolute").css("bottom",0);
            });

        });
```

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rLhHT/

Comment: uploaded the files at http://www.domainandseo.com/bootstrap/index.html. When browser is resized the footer jumps up and browser needs to be refreshed.

Comment: is this code planned to be only used on a desktop or newer mobile browsers? if so, why not using `position: fixed` instead? saves a *lot* of calculations...

Comment: its planned to be responsive, so both desktop and mobile. Hence I figured jquery would be the most efficient. position: fixed is generally frowned upon as the footer can get on top of the content when resized height wise.